# backtick operator

Tags: ruby

The code below, taken from a RubyTapas screencast, prints out a Cowsays message to the terminal.  The class has two methods, `say` and also a backtick method that accepts the url as parameter. It doesn't work without the backtick method, but I don't understand when/how the backtick method is used to print out the cowsays message, because the backtick method is never called. It appears (to me) that you just need to call the `say` method, like so `Cowsays.new.say "Hello, StackOverflow"`. Can you explain how the backtick method gets called in this code?

```
 ______________________
< Hello, StackOverflow >
 ----------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

**code**

```
require 'net/http'
require 'cgi'

class Cowsays
  def `(url)
    URI.parse(url)
  end

  def say(message)
    message = CGI.escape(message)
    Net::HTTP.get_print(`http://www.cowsays.com/cowsay?message=#{message}`)
  end
end

Cowsays.new.say "Hello, StackOverflow"
```

Comment: it is used here: `get_print(\`http://`, so `get_print` gets an `URI` object as argument rather than a string

Comment: And wow, that's some horrible idea.

Comment: @dominikh the guy who made the screencast was just showing us a trick and explicitly said it's not a practice he'd recommend.

Comment: I believe the term I used was "stupid ruby trick" :-)

Comment: P.S. I am perversely pleased that this horrible hack breaks SO's syntax highlighter just as badly as it breaks the one in Emacs :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick that is shown here is, that you can overwrite the backtick operator.

So, instead of writing:

```
Net::HTTP.get_print(URI.parse("http://www.cowsays.com/cowsay?message=#{message}"))
```

You can overwrite the backtick and use

```
Net::HTTP.get_print(`http://www.cowsays.com/cowsay?message=#{message}`)
```

instead.

As already mentioned in the screencast and the comments here - this is just a trick, and it's not advised to actually use it :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be regular quotes like `'` and not backtick. Backtick is used to execute shell commands and returns the results.

For example, to get a listing of files:

```
files = `ls`
```

This is apparently passed through to the backtick method in `Kernel` which you can over-ride if you want. I've never seen this done before and seems like an exceptionally bad idea to do in a production application.